# QT files with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, qt, visual-c++, qt4

I have some file as mentioned below

[image]

I am actually a .NET developer. I am assuming that these are QT files ?

If so, My question is: Do i need to install something in order open these file and to understand the functionality or I can open it directly in Visual Studio ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are not really QT files but [git](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) files.

Seems you do not have QT add-in for MSVC. You can add from [VS plugin](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/04/11/visual-studio-add-in-1-2-1-for-qt-5-released/)

[.gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gitignore/info)

> .gitignore is a file which lists files that git should not include as
>   part of a repository. It is typically used on binaries, temporary
>   files, and packages.

Comment: Can you give us some guide from where to start. Actually I want to open these files in .NET and I have right now only Visual Studio installed.

Comment: right. but, in your first sentence in post, it is mentioned that "These are not really QT files but git files." Sorry I am confused.

Comment: yes.. those files are for version control to maintain different versions of your files. you may not need those to open project in MSVC.

Comment: You will only need the .git files if you want to pull in updates from the remote .git repository or you plan on publishing updates. I doubt this is what you want so you can ignore those files.

Comment: Installation is done and i can open the project file in qt...now i am facing some compilation errors  screencast.com/t/9MhZwp2s

Comment: The .pro file is passing some gcc compiler flags to Visual Studio.

Comment: One of the problems is this line of the .pro "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstack-protector"

Answer (score 2):

Install the qt addin to use the pro file in Visual Studio.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtVSAddin

After installing the addin in Visual Studio it will add a Qt menu to Visual Studio. In that menu there is an option to open a pro file. This will create a Visual Studio workspace from the pro file. This will be a native c++ project not a .NET / CLI.

On top of this addin you must have Qt installed. And this should be a Qt version compiled with the same compiler that you use. From the Qt project page there are binary downloads for several versions of Visual Studio.

http://qt-project.org/downloads

The .git files are from the git version control.

Comment: You may be able to use the Qt dlls in a CLI application however I do not have any experience with that.

Comment: Can you give us some guide from where to start. Actually I want to open these files in .NET and I have right now only Visual Studio installed.

Comment: I am using VS 2010. Can you help us for this ?

Comment: Do I need to install Perl and QT 5.0 also for VS 2010 ?

Comment: You will need perl if you plan on building Qt itself. If not I would not do that.

Comment: You probably want this download: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-msvc2010-x86-offline.exe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44640/discussion-between-abcdefghi-and-drescherjm)

Comment: I said probably because I do not know of the source code. It may not have been updated for Qt-5. If not you then would need a Qt-4.8 download.

Comment: hi..Are u still there ?

Comment: I have done installation of qt and now i can open the project file of qt. Now, can you share the steps how can i open the QT in Visual Studio ? Because there are some compilation errors and I don;t know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show some of the errors please? There could be a few reasons for this.

Comment: From your screenshot it seems the problem is that the pro file is passing gcc options to the Visual Studio compiler. You may have to use QtCreator with mingw as the compiler instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using QT creator to open the file. I am right now don;t have any understanding how to open the qt file in Visual Studio

Comment: By the error that you showed QtCreator was using Visual Studio as the compiler instead of mingw however it was passing gcc command line options to Visual Studio. This package may not work at all with Visual Studio so using the addin may not help.